# Can I create custom regions in Power-BI?

Tags: powerbi, analytics

My organization uses customized regions for management purposes. As an example we have a region called "Latin America" that includes Chile, Mexico, Argentina etc... and I need to create another column that will group countries to specific regions.

In SQL, I would do something like CASE WHEN...Then...

How can I get this done in Power BI?

Comment: In DAX or Power Query?

Comment: If you don't have a table with countries in each region (and don't want to add one), you can add a conditional column to your countries table. https://radacad.com/conditional-column-in-power-bi-using-power-query-you-can-do-anything